# C++ inheritance - inaccessible base?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I seem to be unable to use a base class as a function parameter, have I messed up my inheritance?

I have the following in my main:

```
int some_ftn(Foo *f) { /* some code */ };
Bar b;
some_ftn(&b);
```

And the class Bar inheriting from Foo in such a way:

```
class Bar : Foo
{
public:
    Bar();
    //snip

private:
    //snip
};
```

Should this not work?  I don't seem to be able to make that call in my main function

Answer (score 355, accepted):

You have to do this:

```
class Bar : public Foo
{
    // ...
}
```

The default inheritance type of a `class` in C++ is `private`, so any `public` and `protected` members from the base class are limited to `private`. `struct` inheritance on the other hand is `public` by default.

Answer (score 38):

By default, inheritance is private. You have to explicitly use `public`:

`class Bar : public Foo`

Comment: To expand: In a `class` , inheritance is `private` .  In a `struct` , inheritance is `public` by default.