# container for derived template classes

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++11, smart-pointers

I have the following classes:

```
template <typename T>
class PacketMember
{
public:
    PacketMember() { }

    // Some non-virtual member functions
};


template <typename T>
class NormalMember : PacketMember<T>
{
public:

};

template <typename T>
class CheckSumMember : PacketMember<T>
{
public:

};
```

I would like to have a `std::vector` container containing `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`. so I created one like this:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<PacketMember<unsigned char> > prt;
std::vector<prt> v;
v.push_back(prt(new NormalMember<unsigned char>(header)));
```

but compiler complains about `PacketMember<unsigned char>` being an inaccessible base of `NormalMember<unsigned char>`. I've seen people suggesting on this very website to use a poiter / smart-pointer to the base class and then make it point to derived classes. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @Aesthete I'm sorry, but I don't understand your point.

Comment: `class NormalMember : PacketMember<T>` specifies *private* inheritance. It seems you want *public* inheritance instead: `class NormalMember : public PacketMember<T>`

Comment: Make `NormalMember` inherit publicly by `PacketMember`. The default is private.

Comment: For the next question, please try to reduce the amount of code to the bare minimum that reproduces the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE

Comment: @dyp yes! I can't believe I missed that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @dyp I reduced the code to bare minimum.

Comment: Many thanks. The next tip I can give for future questions is to include the exact error message from the compiler. Also, you'll find some similar questions by searching for "inaccessible base" (maybe plus a "C++" context). The first google hit I find is that one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4847100